# Enviar Email com Ruby

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails, email

Boa noite!
O cenário que me encontro é o seguinte:

Tenho uma tela que apresenta um formulário já preenchido.
No final da tela, existe um botão para enviar o link desde formulário por email.
E é ai que a mágica acontece:

Utilizo AJAX via JavaScript:

```
$('.send_email').click(function () {
    const url = (window.location.href).split("/");
    $.ajax({
        url: " /assessments/"+url[url.length - 2]+"/send_email",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"assessments_id": url[url.length - 2]},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function() {
            alert('Enviado...');
        }
    });
});
```

Ela está funcionando muito bem. Pegando o id contido na URL e passando para solicitar o POST.

No método `send_email`, é onde começa a ficar interessante:
Ele está em um controller exatamente dessa forma:

```
  def send_email
    AssessmentMailer.assessment_report set_assessment
  end
```

O método set_assessment é esse:

```
private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_assessment
  @assessment = Assessment.find(params[:id])
end
```

E está funcionando bem.

O que eu preciso é enviar o email através do `send_email`.
Mas sempre que tento ele retorna com o ***Status 204***

Ao debugar o sistema não vai até a classe/método que é solicitado.

Segue O Mailer

```
class AssessmentMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "mrrafagomides@gmail.com"
  before_action :load_assessments

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.assessment_mailer.assessment_report.subject
  #
  def assessment_report
    mail to: @assessment.collaborator.email , subject: 'QUALIDADE DE VIDA'
  end

  private
  def load_assessments
    @assessment = params[:assessment]
  end
end
```

Segue Model:

```
class Assessment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :collaborator
  paginates_per 10

  after_create :send_report_email

  def send_report_email
    AssessmentMailer.with(assessment: self).assessment_report.deliver_now!
  end
end
```

Quem puder salvar a minha existência Não nada além de gratidão eterna! hahaha.
Brincadeiras a parte...

Comment: O HTTP 204 é de sucesso. Porém sem conteúdo de resposta.

Comment: Sim, durante os debugs eu coloquei no model um "after_find" e passei o método send_report_email ele funciona, só que manda um e-mail pra cada vez que ele faz o find